# mySQL record randomly not storing to dbase

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I have a mySQL dbase, and am using PHP to modify records etc via my web app. After quite some debugging, the mySQL records seem to just be randomly not being stored / updated, and I can't see why.

For some background, the web app does two things - updates the  in the users browser to show what text has just been submitted, and then triggers the php script to store the text to the mySQL record. The  updates, but the insertion of the record to the dbase seems to fail 2 in 5 events (roughly).

Any thoughts on this one?

```
function submit_wallpost($wallpost){
$userid = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

include './mySQL_access.php';

mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (clusterID, userID, postContent) VALUES (111, '$userid', '$wallpost')");

mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I'm going to guess there's something wrong with the code.  I can't see it though, so that's why I am assuming.

Comment: sure - ill post the code now, I was presuming it was an error or something to do with mySQL that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: When you share the code, the likely hood is that someone will fix it!

Comment: @user1953875 The error might be in mySQL, it also might be in your PHP, it also might be on your client side script whatever it may be, it all remains a mystery until we can see some code :)

Comment: Does the clusterID not change? Give a few examples of what you are passing in as $wallpost. Also, what are the field types in the DB?

Comment: @Jon i think $userID comes from $_SESSION while wall post is passed by the parameter in function..

Comment: would you give a try to separate your query from execution for us to see if the data intended to insert have values.. do it like this  `$sql="INSERT INTO wall (clusterID, userID, postContent) VALUES (111, '$userid', '$wallpost')"` and for you query `$result= mysql_query($sql);` then try to do an echo for the `$sql` to check for values to be inserted if present in there.Also try to chech if the code execution failed like this `if($result){ echo 'Success';}else{ echo 'Failed';}`

Answer (score 1):

The code looks okay EXCEPT for the fact that you should be using PDO or mysqli to connect since mysql_functions are deprecated. Regardless all that, some debugging might help you.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall (clusterID, userID, postContent) VALUES (111, '$userid', '$wallpost')");
if (!$query) die(mysql_error());
```

Might help your cause.

Comment: Furthering on from this, you'd probably benefit from moving your database connection out of this particular function!

Comment: @Luke This gives good advice here. You might even look into using an existing database class or something tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

**Your codes seems fines.You should most likely needed to check where errors occur.**

1.Checking values intended to insert from the query.Try to separte your query statement from execution by defining first your query.This would be a great deal checking the values intended to submit using `echo` and also you can try to run it in your db `sql`

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO wall (clusterID, userID, postContent) VALUES (111, '$userid', '$wallpost')"
```

2.Try do check whether your `$sql` statement execution failed or not.This idea will return back an `echo` statement.

```
 if($result){
      echo 'Success';
   }
   else{
    echo 'Failed';
 }
```

Into these we will have a general idea where the codes stops that makes the query failed